# Construct a dictionary by using another dictionary keys and values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have dictionary below.

```
 my_d =    {'country': ['Germany',"France"],
     'games': ['Football,Motorsport'],
     'bayern': ['Muller']}
```

I need to create a dictionary using above key and values

- Each key will be added `keyword` in the output `country.keyword`

```
    {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "terms": {
                "country.keyword": [
                  "Germany",
                  "France"
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "terms": {
                "games.keyword": [
                  "Football",
                  "Motorsport"
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "bayern.keyword": ["Muller"]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

if `my_d = {'country': ['Germany',"France"]}` or  my_d = {'country': ['Germany',"France"],
'games': None,
'bayern':None}

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "country.keyword": [
              "Germany",
              "France"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.  The transformation algorithm is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally I would recommend using Elasticsearch 3rd party python package do query Elasticsearch, but I believe this code should work (python 3.5+):

```
must_clauses = [{f"{key}.keyword": value} for key, value in my_d.items()]
terms = [{"terms": must_clause} for must_clause in must_clauses]
query_template = {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": 
            terms
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Nice bit of code - I'm interested in your adjustment to meet the case for bayern.

Comment: @Mark
That can't be done, without providing the relevant operation (match, terms) as additional information within the dict, or having a secondary data structure that provides this information.

As long as there's no structure to it (e.g, first 2 will always use terms, and the 3rd, will use match), this as an approach isn't good as it will break easily when a change is required.

Having a dict that maps the keyword to the type of search (or holding it within the dict as another attribute) will make it possible